# Potential difference relation with Electric field intensity

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, voltage

An equipotential surface has the same potential at all points and thus zero potential difference between any two points.

[image]

Consider the situation 2 as in the figure, If I use $E=-ΔV/Δr$ to find electric field intensity between those two points then electric field intensity should be zero as $ΔV =0$, but that is not the case (It is actually constant).

I know that we derived the relationship between potential gradient and electric field intensity by using two points located between two different equipotential surfaces, so does this mean we cannot use this relation for two points on the same equipotential surface? If so, why can't we?

If I intuitively think about situation 2, the closest I can get to is that the direction of electric field is not directed between those two points (it is perpendicular), as compared to the original situation 1 in which E has the direction Between those points (ignoring positive or negative for a while).But I dont know how it effects this relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electric field is given by the gradient of the potential, E = -$\nabla$$\Phi$, and is a vector. If you calculate the gradient as in situation 2, its component in that direction is 0 so the component of the electric field in that direction is 0, as you know. That doesn't mean the electric field itself is 0. It has a component in the radial direction which is found as in situation 1 where the component of the gradient in the radial direction is non-zero.